# How do I change the virtualbox "Host Key"?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm not using an apple keyboard and don't have a Left ⌘.  Can I change the "Host Key" to be the Right ⌘?  How?

Answer (score 5):

The GUI setting is under Preferences -> Input -> Virtual Machine:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This sets the host key to the right command key (VirtualBox 4.3.10):

```
VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/Input/HostKeyCombination 54
```

The command will accept any value, but VirtualBox will not start if you supply an invalid value.  55 is the standard left command key, 61 is the right alt key.  I found the values via educated guesses (aka "playing around").

Comment: Your sir are awesome. Why is this not an option in the VirtualBox GUI Ill never understand.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug that appeared in VirtualBox 4.3.8 (maybe earlier?) that prevents the Virtualbox “Host Key” from being changed. [It got fixed](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12828) in [VirtualBox 4.3.14](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.14/). If you are using a VirtualBox version that is affected by the bug, here is [a workaround](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13087):

> After changing the host key, select some other configurable shortcut
>   (no need to change it), and then click OK.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding this to [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) in KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
```

It might not work if you don't have a physical keyboard with a left command though.

Comment: thx. It's an idea;haven't tried yet as I'm holding out to see if anyone knows of a native way to do it.  Turns out it's not too critical provided I ensure that the "mini toolbar" is enabled for full-screen mode as that allows me use the mouse to get out again... (provided the guest has a working mouse).